# Migrating from jQuery to Prototype (code snippet)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, prototypejs

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I am migrating from jQuery to Prototype but I am a newbie with the first JavaScript framework so I have some trouble. I would like to write the jQuery version of the following Prototype code:

```
  page.select("#test_id").each do |element|
    element.replace( "Test text )
  end
```

**How can I do? What is the code?**

Comment: I've never used prototype...does that select all the sub elements of the object with id #test_id? or do you have more than one element with that id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#test_id').html('Test text');
```

or

```
$('.test_class').each(function(){
    $(this).html('Test text');
});
```

Comment: The above code will match only the first '#test_id'. I have many of that on one page.

Comment: You may consider that when you have more than one element with the same id on the page you should probably use a class instead. The id selector in jQuery picks up the first item with the id only.

Comment: Thank, I switch from 'ids' to 'classes'.